# Logarithms and the Identity Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

My teacher today asked us how can we use the [Identity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) to show why can't we define the complex logarithm on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. Can someone give me a hint on how can I do this?

Comment: Follow the logarithm along the unit circle.

Comment: Do you mean $log(e^{it})$, where $t\in[0,2\pi ]$?

Comment: Yes, that. If the logarithm were continuous, where would you end when you start at $\log 1 = 0$?

Comment: If I take the principal branch, then I would conclude that $log(1)=0$ and $log(1)=2\pi i$?

Comment: Yes. So the domain of a continuous branch of the logarithm can't contain the unit circle. Pretty much the same argument shows it cannot contain the trace of any closed curve that winds around the origin.

Comment: But I didn't used the Identity Theorem!

Comment: One could argue that you used it when concluding $\log e^{it} = it$ for all $t$. Or maybe you used the uniqueness of lifts for the covering $\exp \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^\times$. If you don't argue stepwise, but go immediately from $\log e^{it} = it$ in a small neighbourhood of $1$ to $\log e^{it} = it$ on the entire circle, you need one of the global principles. But true, yelling "identity theorem" is a bit of a stretch. However, I don't see how else one would show it.

Comment: Me neither, but thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm should be the inverse of the exponential function $z\mapsto e^z$, but that function is not one-to-one, since $e^{z+2\pi i} = e^z$.

The identity theorem entails that if you have two functions defined on some connected open neighborhood of, for example $1$, and the values of all their derivatives, starting with the $0$th derivative agree with those of the real function $x\mapsto\log x$ at that point, then they're equal.  But suppose you have an open neighborhood of $1$ that also contains $-1$ and includes the whole upper half-plane, and another open neighborhood containing those two points and including the whole lower half-plane.  There is a function having the right values of all derivatives, starting with the $0$th, at $1$, that is defined in the first neighborhood, and another in the second, and their values do not agree at $-1$.  This doesn't contradict the identity theorem since they're not both defined on a common open neighborhood.